# How do I pass in an array of integers to a method without declaring the array to a variable and passing it in?

Tags: java

I have a method that checks if a given integer array is alternating as in positive and negative numbers. This method takes in an integer array as the parameter and I need to pass in the array as a set of numbers instead of the usual way where I assign the array that is being passed in, to a variable and then passing it in.

The code is below.

```
public class PositivesNegatives {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        alternateSign([3, -2, 5, -5, 2, -8]);
        alternateSign([-6, 1, -1, 4, -3]);
        alternateSign([4, 4, -2, 3, -6, 10]);
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    private boolean alternateSign(int[] num) {
    boolean t = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            if(num[0] < 0 && num[0]!= 0) {
                if(i % 2 != 0) {
                    if(num[i]>0)
                        t = true;
                }
            }else if(num[0] > 0 && num[0] != 0) {
                if(i % 2 != 0) {
                    if(num[0]<0)
                        t = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return t;
    }
}
```

I tried searching it up but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: `alternateSign(new int[] {3, -2, 5, -5, 2, -8});` also, you could eliminate `t` and `return true` at any point you set `t` to `true` (since it will always be `true` once you set it to `true`).